# Python list with json saved as a one-String list

Tags: python, json, list, file, append

I have the following problem:

```
def guardar_datos_en_json(dato, nombre_archivo):
    try:
        with open(nombre_archivo, "a") as contenedor:            
            json.dump(dato, contenedor)
    except:
        raise

def cargar_datos_de_json(nombre_archivo):
    lista = []    
    with open(nombre_archivo,"r") as contenedor:
        for linea in contenedor:            
            lista.append(linea)                                   
    linea = json.dumps(linea)                           
    return lista
```

This function returns a list based in a json file, the problem is that when I make its tests,instead of returning a list, it returns a list with one string.

If for example I save the numbers 1 and 2 in a json file, when I use the function cargar_datos_de_json, it will return ['12'] instead of [1, 2], does anyone know why?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try checking that the json file contents look like what you expect?

Comment: what is your dato

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

When you dump the list using json.dump it will write like below

```
import json
list = [1, 2]
json.dumps(list) # '[1, 2]'
```

I think you need to do as follow

```
import ast 
def cargar_datos_de_json(nombre_archivo):
    with open(nombre_archivo,"r") as contenedor:
        lista = ast.literal_eval(contenedor) 
    return lista
```